# Bounding box generation, retaining fields?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector-grid, bbox

I generated a bounding box by calculating the extent of each feature using "Polygon from layer extent..." tool located in "Vector/Research Tools" which works great but I lost the fields, especially the name of each polygon. Does anyone know how to keep the fields in the process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use another tool through the menu Processing - Toolbox - QGIS geoalgorithms -Vector geometry tools - Bounding boxes.  The tools looks almost the same than the one you used but instead of computing some new statistical attributes this tool just copies all the attributes from the source layer.

[image]

Comment: I now think this is the answer, but this tool is only in QGIS version 2.18.15... missing from QGIS version 2.14.21

Answer (score 2):

After generating a bounding box from the polygon layer, you can use Join attributes by location to copy the information of the original polygon to the newly created polygon extent. Go to `Processing toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Join attributes by location`.

In the following example, I have a polygon (cyan color) and I generated a polygon extent (light brown color), and the attributes are shown in the image below:

[image]

Using Join attributes by location:

[image]

- Target polygon: Polygon extent
- Join vector layer: The original
- polygon Geometric predicate: intersects

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: I wonder how well it works when bounding boxes intersect many polygons as happens with adjacent polygons.

Comment: @user30184 in this case, it is better to use `within` located under polygon Geometric predicate rather than `intersect`, and since the bounding should cover completely the the target polygon, using `within` can solve the problem.

Comment: That's better but it is still possible to have other polygons which are within the same bounding box. In your example image there is plenty of room in every corner.

Comment: @user30184 it is possible, but that depends on how the polygons are distributed. The solution I presented may solve the problem, but the asker may encounter some troubles if there are many polygons fitted within the same bounding box which can be adjusted manually in this case.